# About dipole moment

Tags: electrostatics, definition, dipole, dipole-moment

[image]

The picture is taken from wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment

I don't understand the formula when it comes to continuous charge distribution.

But I understand this one:  $$ \vec{p} = q  \vec{d} $$
where dipole moment vector $ \vec{p}$ is equal to charge $q$ times the displacement vector $ \vec{d}$ that separates two opposite charges.

Comment: [Please don’t post screenshots of text](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the relation between charge and charge density(surface, volume)?

$$\rm dq\sim \sigma \rm dA\sim\rho\rm d\tau$$

You can find clear relation between them by integrating and you can plug the equation in $\vec p=q\vec d$. We can do it. But, if we have specific amount of charges (e.g. dipole, quadrupole) then we can't take density. We do taylor expansion for multipole (also called multipole expansion).

Comment: [Check it out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion)

Comment: So surface charge is the same charge but distributed over the surface? So sigma is charge per unit area then when multiplied by area becomes the total charge on the surface?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand why can't we take the density of charge?

Comment: @user134613 that's true, you can take charge density (volume or area depending on your surface). But if you are given that a sphere has quadruple or 12 charges  (and their distances are same). Then you have to do multipole expansion, it may look like continuous charge in a specific surface. But you will get better/proper result if you choose multipole rather than surface charge density or volume charge density. $$q=\int \sigma \rm dA=\int \rho\rm d\tau$$